# how to use MathML in HTML

Tags: html, mathml

I'm trying to displaying math formula on a web page.
But when I write html code like following

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Binomial Theorem</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Binomial Theorem:</p>
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mrow>
        <msup>
            <mfenced>
                <mrow>
                    <mi>a</mi>
                    <mo>+</mo>
                    <mi>b</mi>
                </mrow>
            </mfenced>
            <mn>2</mn>
        </msup>
        <mo>=</mo>
        <msup>
            <mrow>
                <mi>a</mi>
            </mrow>
            <mn>2</mn>
        </msup>
        <mo>+</mo>
        <msup>
            <mrow>
                <mi>b</mi>
            </mrow>
            <mn>2</mn>
        </msup>
        <mo>+</mo>
        <mrow>
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mi>a</mi>
            <mi>b</mi>
        </mrow>
    </mrow>
</math>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result is just

**Binomial Theorem:**

**a + b   2  = a  2  + b  2  + 2 a b**

It is not like a formula

help me to use MathML in HTML 
Thanks,

Comment: MathML is not well supported http://caniuse.com/#feat=mathml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MathML isn't supported by all popular user agents. Firefox 3.5 or later releases, for example, do support it:

[image: The MathML snippet rendered by Firefox 3.5]

Comment: Bob Mathews answer below works well for all browsers. Tested in Chrome, IE and FireFox

Answer (score 4):

I would make 3 changes to your page:

1. Include a DOCTYPE declaration as the first line of code. `<!DOCTYPE html>` identifies this page to the browser as an HTML5 page.
2. I'd omit the namespace declaration from the `html` element. It doesn't hurt anything to have it there, but it's not necessary. You're probably going to include it on each `math` element anyway.
3. If you add this as the last line above `</head>`, the math will be visible in all browsers, not just Firefox:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>`

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1):

MathML is currently supported only on Firefox browsers. Try on Firefox browser.